# Rethinkdb, koa, ejs ,angular - realtime update in html

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rethinkdb, koa, nosql

I'm trying to get a real time update in html using Rethinkdb, koa, ejs and angular. something like [Rethinkdb](https://www.rethinkdb.com) main page example [streaming rethinkdb results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqp7D.png)

I have looked in a few examples on the web but could not managed to recreate anything with the above stack.

How could that be achieved ?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Hey Flik, can you mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 2):

We have plenty of example repos RethinkDB Github organization page.

https://github.com/rethinkdb/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=example

You should definitely start there.

Comment: Tnx. i looked at the link, there are no examples or clues on the refernce i mentioned (rethinkdb web site example).

Comment: While we don't have a specific example where we demo those specific results from a changefeed, all the examples feature a changefeed in some way or another. The feature works just the same. Why are you looking for this example in particular?

Comment: I'm developing a web app and I will need a real time update on list from the db, every time the db will change I want the list to be updated at real time.

Answer (score 0):

I made a screencast that might be helpful:
http://knowthen.com/episode-10-building-realtime-applications-just-got-easy/

Here is the corresponding repo:
https://github.com/knowthen/Episode-10-Building-realtime-web-applications

Comment: Thank you, I will take a second look at that.